# Old input for array?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have `foreach` and inside `foreach` i have input like this:

```
 <input type="text" id="text-title" name="article_title[{{$language->code}}]" value="{{ old('article_title[$language->code]') }}" class="form_input"  />
```

Im trying to add old input like this but its not working. Any suggestion how can i use old for array?

Also i tried this but also not working:

```
  <input type="text" id="text-title" name="article_title[{{$language->code}}]" value="{{ old('article_title.0') }}" class="form_input"  />
```

I have validation only for first iteration if that means anything for you.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You should be able to access the index off of your language code:

```
value="{{ old('article_title.'.$language_code) }}"
```

Answer (score 4):

you can use the old to return old value as an array

```
# old('article_title') => array

value="{{ old('article_title')[0][$language_code] ?? "" }}"

# "0" is an example of an index. You can programmatically add index
```

Comment: Trying to access array offset on value of type null

Comment: @mercury
` value="{{ old('article_title')[0][$language_code] ?? "" }}" `

# "0" is an example of an index. You can programmatically add index