# Laravel old() input array with a default value?

Tags: laravel

If it is not an array, I can just enter like below

```
<input value="{{old('name','ali')}}">
```

so the default value will display `ali`

But when it old('name') is an array, how can i write my default value like the previous one to, or i can only use isset() to check?

```
<input value="{{old('name')[$i]}}">
```

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure is there any other solution.
But, please try this:

```
{{@old('name')[$i]}}
```

(add `@` before)

Comment: but this code does not put **ali** as my default value

Comment: @Zachary how about
`
old("name[$i]", $default)
`

Comment: this will have the default value, but the old value it not working because it is an array

Comment: @Zachary did you try ` old("name.$i", $default)`. I get it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42050732/old-input-for-array