# How to get old input value from name input array laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have this code

```
@foreach($questions as $question_name => $question_details)
                            <h5>{{ $question_name }}</h5>
                            @foreach($question_details as $question_id => $question_description)
                                <p class="ms-3">{{ $question_description }}</p> 
                                <input type="hidden" name="question_id[]" value="{{ $question_id }}"/>
                                <textarea name="answers[]" class="form-control ms-3" cols="30" rows="2" placeholder="Your answer here.."></textarea>
                            @endforeach
                        @endforeach
```

And when I submit a form with some empty values, the answers that I got also get deleted if some error occurs I tried this to get back my old inputs but it didn't bring me anything

I tried

```
<textarea name="answers[]" class="form-control ms-3" cols="30" rows="2" placeholder="Your answer here..">{{ old('answers') }}</textarea>

<textarea name="answers[]" class="form-control ms-3" cols="30" rows="2" placeholder="Your answer here..">{{ old('answers[]') }}</textarea>

<textarea name="answers[]" class="form-control ms-3" cols="30" rows="2" placeholder="Your answer here..">{{ old('answers.0') }}</textarea>
```

But nothing really succeed to bring me back the old values that I typed can someone help me with that?

Comment: could you please share what does `dd(session()->getOldInput())` reutrns, add this while submitting.

Comment: It shows me an empty array

Comment: Nobody can help without knowing what your controller does. For format use `old('answers[0]')` or `old('answers.0')`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42050732/old-input-for-array

Answer (score 1):

When you submit a form that has a HTML array (`name="answers[]"`), it will be converted to a proper PHP array in the backend. This also means that the values will be indexed like a PHP array is always indexed. If you have three rows, even without values, you can expect it to look like so:

```php
dd($request->input('answers');
/* Output: [
    0 => null,
    1 => null,
    2 => null,
]; */
```

When you then fetch `old('answers')`, you will get an `array`. If you want the second answer, you will have to fetch `old('answers.1')`.

If you want the structure to be more clear and dynamic, you could use your question ID as index parameter:

```html
@foreach($question_details as $question_id => $question_description)
    <p class="ms-3">{{ $question_description }}</p> 
    <textarea name="answers[{{$question_id}}]" class="form-control ms-3" cols="30" rows="2" placeholder="Your answer here...">{{old("answers.{$question_id}")}}</textarea>
@endforeach
```

Now your `array` will be keyed by your question IDs. If, however, you don't want to do that, you can also key by loop index:

```
@foreach($question_details as $question_id => $question_description)
    <p class="ms-3">{{ $question_description }}</p> 
    <input type="hidden" name="question_id[{{$loop->index}}]" value="{{ $question_id }}"/>
    <textarea name="answers[{{$loop->index}}]" class="form-control ms-3" cols="30" rows="2" placeholder="Your answer here...">{{old("answers.{$loop->index}")}}</textarea>
@endforeach
```

You can read more about the `$loop` variable [here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#the-loop-variable)

Answer (score 0):

```
<textarea name="answers[]" 
    class="form-control ms-3" cols="30" rows="2" 
    placeholder="Your answer here.."
    >{{ old('answers.' . $loop->index) }}</textarea>
```

Comment: It helps when you explain why your code works and why the question's code does not. This piece of code might work but it's probably not clear to the asker as to why it works.

Comment: @codingbruh  Your edit of my answer introduces an issue. Now the content of the text area will include an extra and unwanted newline .  The text area content should be immediately wrapped by the `>` and `<` .  Please revert your edit

Comment: Alright. Fair Enough